# The Grid Mesh Generator has changed its outputs, how do I turn its mesh output to vertices and indices?

Tags: animation, animation-nodes

I'm just trying to follow this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q1lY6VXBQ_E&list=PLJSCK4DjIWhk-JIGOIJKLUB1bGXfDBgzZ&index=7) but when I try doing the same in my computer, the output of the Grid Mesh is different:

[image: Grid mesh before/after]

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2):

I guess the docs were not updated.

What you're looking for is "Mesh Info", it breaks down the information necessary from a Mesh Input

[image: Mesh Info Node example]